# linker error: missing vtable

Tags: c++, objective-c, linker-errors

I'm getting a linker error in xcode and I'm having a hard time understanding and finding the problem. This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

---

My `Instrument class` looks like this:

```
class Instrument {

private:

public:

    virtual float getSample(Note &note);
    Instrument(){}

};
```

And it's implemented by my `Synth class`:

```
class Synth : public Instrument{

private:
    Volume volume;
public:
    Synth(){}
    void setVolume(float aVolume);
    virtual float getSample(Note &note);
};
```

And I'm using Instrument as a member in my `Track class`:

```
class Track {
public:
    bool muted;
    Instrument instrument;
Track(){
    this->muted = false;
}
};
```

Any ideas what is causing the problem? And I have one more question: If have a `Track` object, what is the best way to initialize it's `instrument` member as a `Synth`? Would this work?

```
Track track;
track.instrument = Synth();
```

Comment: you forgot to mention anything about the implementation of the classes' functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Note in error says, you need to provide definition of virtual function which is missing I guess : `Instrument::getSample(Note &note);`

but I guess you need pure virtual function, make it:

```
class Instrument {
//...
public:
    virtual float getSample(Note &note) =0;
    Instrument(){}
};
```

if that's not the case , post more code and check your code on different compiler , might be your compiler is buggy